# bad padding exception in java (RSA Decryption)

Tags: c#, java, rsa, encryption

I am facing some issues when decrypt a RSA Base64 encoded string in java.RSA encrypted string is made by c#.Net.

Actually, I created a public and private key by using java. Then I exchanged the public key to .Net Team. They encrypted a string by using the public key with the use of `RSACryptoServiceProvider` class.

.Net code:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(keySize);
rsa.FromXmlString(publicKey);
.......
.......
byte[] encryptedBytes = rsa.Encrypt(tempBytes, false);
Array.Reverse(encryptedBytes);
stringBuilder.Append(Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytes));
```

Java decrypt Code:

```
   public static void doDecrypt( BigInteger  modules, BigInteger  d , String encrypted )
    {
            try {
                    byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decodeBase64( encrypted );
                    KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
                    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");

                    RSAPrivateKeySpec privSpec = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(modules, d);
                    PrivateKey privKey = factory.generatePrivate(privSpec);

                    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privKey);
                    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(decodedBytes) ;
                    System.out.println("decrypted: " + new String(decrypted));
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
```

While decrypting the string, It says the following error.

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Data must start with zero
   at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(RSAPadding.java:308)
   at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:255)
   at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.a(DashoA13*..)
   at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(DashoA13*..)
   at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(DashoA13*..)
```

then , I tried with

```
 Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/NoPadding");
```

But, It gives junk characters, Which I could not relate to my desired plain text.
I think , Somewhere I am missing to do something.Please guide me on this.

Comment: For a start, the C# code does `Array.Reverse(encryptedBytes);` but the Java code does not reverse the reversed bytes back. Solution: remove `Array.Reverse(encryptedBytes);` from the C# code.

Comment: Will it works , if perform the reverse once again in java before doing the decrypt.

Comment: You should use the same padding mode for both, namely OAEP.

Comment: @sat I think that reversing the bytes should do the trick. Even though RSA is a number calculation, the RSA output should always be big endian (otherwise it would not be compatible), so I don't know why your colleagues called `Array.Reverse` on it.

Answer (score -1):

```
rsa.Encrypt(tempBytes, false)
```

leads to PKCS#1 v1.5 padding. So you must use the same on the java side. Try to use

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
```

I think the windows API uses ECB by default, but you might want to try other modes like CBC or CFB too.

Comment: What he should do is switch to OAEP for both. PKCS#1 v1.5 padding for encryption should be avoided.

Comment: And those block cipher chaining modes don't make much sense with RSA. .net encrypts a single block with RSA.

Comment: Right. But depending on the block length a multi-block operation might be needed.

Comment: In that case one would use a hybrid cryptosystem. Most chaining modes like CBC can't even work with RSA, since RSA has smaller input than output due to padding.

Comment: I agree with you about the OAEP. But he uses PKCS padding on the .NET side, and I just wanted to point him to the appropriate setting in java. About that CBC stuff, I must say that I have no idea how microsoft actually implemented the RSA stuff, and also how sun did with java. So trying different settings would surely not hurt.

Comment: @PeterF that should be `"PKCS1Padding"`, obviously. `"PKCS5Padding"` is used for 8 byte block ciphers.

Comment: -1 because this uncorrected answer led the lazy OP to copy and paste his way to another error [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577185/how-to-solve-the-nosuchalgorithmexception-in-java)