# How to solve the NoSuchAlgorithmException in java?

Tags: java, exception, encryption, rsa

I am trying to decrypt the data using RSA Algorithm. While doing the decryption, I am getting an exception.That is,

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting RSA/ECB/PKCS5Padding
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(DashoA13*..)
```

How to solve this exception? Currently, I am using `java version "1.6.0_26"`.

Comment: Could you post an example of your code?

Comment: The problem is in the comments of the answer you copied. You should always read the comments as someone has made the effort to provide additional information.

Comment: I do fully agree with @GregS here :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a typo. The correct name for RSA with PKCS #1 v1.5 padding is "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding".
Generally, it is a good idea to compare with a list of available algorithms.
E.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333504/how-can-i-list-the-available-cipher-algorithms) contains some ways to print such a list.

(And of course using OAEP instead of v1.5 padding would be preferable, especially if your
main field is not cryptography).

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the library you use cna't decrypt the data because there isn't an algorithm in the Lib which decrypts RSA.
You can use a library like Bouncy Calste or GNU Crypto to decrypt data using RSA. There are plenty of samples how to do this on the web.