# How to reverse the byte array in java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I reverse an int array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137755/how-do-i-reverse-an-int-array-in-java)

What is the equivalent function in java to perform `Array.Reverse(bytearray)` in C# ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137755/how-do-i-reverse-an-int-array-in-java

Comment: Do you want to do that in Java or C#?

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/Reversestheorderofthegivenbytetypearray.htm

Comment: Can you say why you need to do this because if you want to switch between little endian and big endian there are much better ways of doing this?

Comment: Actually, we are trying to decrypt the .net encrypted string(RSA).In that, we faced some padding issue.To resolve, we wanted to reverse the byte array.For more information click [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543933/bad-padding-exception-in-java-rsa-decryption)

Answer (score 22):

```
public static void reverse(byte[] array) {
      if (array == null) {
          return;
      }
      int i = 0;
      int j = array.length - 1;
      byte tmp;
      while (j > i) {
          tmp = array[j];
          array[j] = array[i];
          array[i] = tmp;
          j--;
          i++;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use `Collections.reverse` on a `list` returned by `Arrays.asList` operated on an `Array`: -

```
    Byte[] byteArr = new Byte[5];

    byteArr[0] = 123; byteArr[1] = 45;
    byteArr[2] = 56;  byteArr[3] = 67;
    byteArr[4] = 89;

    List<Byte> byteList = Arrays.asList(byteArr); 

    Collections.reverse(byteList);  // Reversing list will also reverse the array

    System.out.println(byteList);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(byteArr));
```

**OUTPUT**: -

```
[89, 67, 56, 45, 123]
[89, 67, 56, 45, 123]
```

**UPDATE**: -
Or, you can also use: [`Apache Commons`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) [`ArrayUtils#reverse`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/index.html) method, that directly operate on primitive type array: -

```
byte[] byteArr = new byte[5];
ArrayUtils.reverse(byteArr);
```

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Didn't knew that. At first I thought you meant something else. Thanks. Edited. :)

Comment: And as a convenience, it is most practical to print an array's contents using `Arrays.toString(array)`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Okay. I always used array.toString() and got wierd `HashCodes`.. :( Thanks a million for that..

Answer (score 2):

You may use `java.util.Collections.reverse()`. It takes `java.util.List` as an input argument. So you should convert your byteArray into a List either by doing `Arrays.asList(byteArray)` or by creating an List object and adding byte values into it.