# Create a BitSet's toByteArray method (Wrong byte order)

Tags: java, bit-fields, bittorrent

So i'm working on a bittorrent project. I need to create a bitfield according to number of piece. So i use BitSet but the problem is, the method toByteArray doesn't return the byte array in the order of byte that i wanted.

Eg:

```
//number of piece=11 
bitSet.set(5,16);  //following bittorrent specification
```

`bitSet.toByteArray()` -> `0xe0ff` (this is the byte that i get)

But what i want is `0xffe0`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use the bit-manipulation operators, like we did in the old days. Or just manipulate the order of the bytes.

Comment: `0xe0ff` is not a byte, it's two bytes in unknown order. `bitSet.toByteArray()` actually returns `[-32, -1]`, aka `[0xe0, 0xff]`. As **documented** in the javadoc of [`toByteArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#toByteArray--): *Returns a byte array containing a **little-endian** representation of all the bits in this bit set.* --- If you want big-endian order, just reverse the bytes of the returned array, see: [How to reverse the byte array in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12893758/5221149).

Answer (score 1):

This is due to big-endian vs little-endian mismatch.  `BitSet` is strictly bit-wise little-endian.  `BitSet#toByteArray()` handles reversing the *bit-order*, but outputs little-endian bytes.  So you'll have to rearrange the *bytes* yourself to match the desired order.  The desired order will depend on the size of the "word" in your output data structure.

If the output is a `short`, you swap bytes 2 at a time, but if it's a `long` you'll need to reverse each set of 4 output bytes.  It's possible to do this with a `ByteBuffer` but it's probably more work, unless you're already using `ByteBuffer`s.

Unfortunately, there isn't a `BitSet.toShortArray()`, which would do what you want.

You might find the Wikipedia article [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) useful.