# What is the default padding used for RSACryptoServiceProvider?

Tags: c#, .net

[Looking at the documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider?view=net-5.0), I can't seem to find any information about the default padding scheme.

Edit: In case it's not clear, I'm asking about C#.

Comment: What ever you want!!! The default padding in JAVA and c# are different.  Either can be used but you must use the same padding mode to encrypt and decrypt.

Comment: I'm not asking about what I should use, I'm asking about the default when nothing is specified.

Comment: It depends on application.  As I said Java and c# default to different modes.

Comment: As per the tags, and linked documentation, I'm asking about C#.

Comment: You never said c#.  See answer at following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543933/bad-padding-exception-in-java-rsa-decryption/12546032

Comment: There is no default padding scheme. You must specify the padding to use in the `Encrypt` and `Decrypt` call.

Comment: If that's the case then where is the padding being set for this code? https://github.com/geel9/SteamAuth/blob/96ca6af3eb03d1a45f7fbff78851f055ba47c0d4/SteamAuth/UserLogin.cs#L77-L85 Am I missing something painfully obvious?